# "Нечасто" против "не часто"

Tags: значение-слов, частица-не, наречия

> 1) Этот метод используется **нечасто**.
>
> 2) Этот метод используется **не часто**.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что в первом примере говорится, что метод используется *редко*, а во втором примере, что метод используется *редко* **или** *с нормальной частотой*?

Comment: С нормальной частотой - это как? Не часто - отрицается, что часто, но это не означает, что редко, скорее бессистемно(то редко, то часто, но так как это не всегда, то нельзя сказать "часто").Главное, что не используется часто, поэтому и раздельно.

Comment: @Людмила: Это уже каждый сам чувствует, что такое нормальное частота -- для каждого может быть по-разному. Например, нормальная частота хождения в магазин какая? Для меня -- 3-4 раза в неделю, а для кого-то другая.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В первом случае вы утверждаете, что метод используется нечасто (= редко).
НЕ здесь — приставка, придающая слову противоположное значение.

Во втором случае вы отрицаете, что метод используется часто.
НЕ — отрицательная частица.

Ваше понимание смысла высказывания верно.

Answer (score 1):

Пожалуй, "не часто" и "нечасто" в этой фразе – полные синонимы. Думаю, что не совсем правильно понимаете. Слишком уж формальный у вас подход. "Нечасто" вовсе не означает "редко". Нечасто – обычно чаще, чем редко. Такая вот градация. Ну, так же, как небольшой больше маленького, это не совсем синонимы.